# How to correctly load a different version of main menu based on the user language in WordPress? Is it a good solution?

Tags: php, theme-development, menus, themes

I have the following problem developing a WordPress theme and I am here to ask you if this solution could be a good solution or if exist some better way to do.

I have a custom WP theme and into this theme there is a main menu. The website is multilanguage (italian and english) so I have to load the Italian main menu (contains the menu item in Italian language) if the visitor is italian and the main menu have to been loaded in the English version if the user is not italian.

So I have found this solution:

In the WP backend I create 2 different menus: **Menu 1** and **Menu 2** (the first one having voices in Italian language and the second one in English language)

Then inside my theme (into the **header.php** file) I declare something like it:

1. First I detect the user language tacking it from **$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']**
2. Then, I use this value to show Menu 1 if the **$lang** value is **it* or **Menu 2 if the **$lang** value is **en**

Something like this:

```
<?php 
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    //echo "Language is $lang";  IT SEEMS TO WORK: MY LANGUAGE IS CORRECTLY RECOGNIZED AS it

    if($lang == it){      // If the user is Italian load Italian menu

        wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu' => 'Menu 1', 
        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
        'depth' => 2,
        'container' => 'div', 
        /*'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-default',*/
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback', 
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
     }
     else{            // If the user is not italian load English menu
        wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu' => 'Menu 2', 
        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
        'depth' => 2,
        'container' => 'div', 
        /*'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-default',*/
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback', 
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
     }
?>
```

I think that in this way have to correctly work (I have to try) but, is it a good solution or could I do better in some other way?

Comment: Hm. Is this about switching menus or figuring out which language a user has chosen?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used Polylang plugin and 3 languages. So i created 3 menus like this: https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4o9rz/opx5.
after that i checked the language and displayed the correct menu,like this:

```
<?php 
            if (get_locale() == 'en_US') {
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'menu' => 'Primary Menu En',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                ));
            } else if (get_locale() == 'ro_RO') {
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'menu' => 'Primary Menu Ro',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                ));
            } else if (get_locale() == 'ru_RU') {
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'menu' => 'Primary Menu Ru',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                ));
            }
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Websites that uses Multi Lingual WordPress uses WPML plugin. It has a build in Menu Sync feature that will add different version/translation of menu for each language. Its pretty much the standard to go nowadays in terms of WordPress sites having more than one language. Check this link for more info:

https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-menus/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct solution but as I am also using custom theme and so on I leaned towards creating menus in such manner I can use the advantage of the "suffixes" or "slugs" of the language plugin to determine the current language.

so create suffix variable string

```
$lang_suffix = "_". pll_current_language('slug');
```

And then just call for it. Surely you need to create on your own few menus which will need to be in convention "Menu_EN"..."Menu_ES"... and so on.
Also little bit of if() checks would be good not to bump into non existing value. But you got the point.

```
 $lang_suffix = "_". pll_current_language('slug');
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'Menu'.$lang_suffix,
                    //'theme_location'    => 'primary-menu',
                    'depth'             => 5,
                    'container'         => 'ul',
                    'container_class'   => '',
                    'menu_class'        => 'text-uppercase navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
            ?>
```